# rxjs - how can you create another observable from an observable but ignore its output in the parent observable?

Tags: rxjs, rxjs-observables, rxjs-pipeable-operators

I have a situation where I have an observable, and for each emitted item, I want to create another observable, but ignore that observable's value and instead return the result of the first observable.
For example, if I click a button, I want to track something that happens in another button, only when the first button is toggled on.

I can do this now, sort of, with a hack, by taking the output of the child observable and piping it to a `mapTo` with the parent's value.  You can see it in this code, which can be played with in a [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/rxjs-playground-forked-61tgl?file=/src/index.js):

```js
import { fromEvent, from } from "rxjs";
import { mapTo, switchMap, tap, scan  } from "rxjs/operators";

const buttonA = document.getElementById("a");
const buttonB = document.getElementById("b");

const textA = document.querySelector('#texta');
const textB = document.querySelector('#textb');

fromEvent(buttonA, 'click').pipe(
  // this toggles active or not.
  scan((active) => !active, false),
  switchMap(active => {

    if (active) {
      const buttonBClicks$ = fromEvent(buttonB, 'click');
 
      // here we can observe button b clicks, when button a is toggled on.
      return buttonBClicks$.pipe(
        // count the sum of button b clicks since button a was toggled on.
        scan((count) => count+1, 0),
        tap(buttonBCount  => {
          textB.value = `button b count ${buttonBCount}`;
        }),
        // ignore the value of the button b count for the final observable output. 
        mapTo(active)
      )
    } else {
      textB.value = ``;

      return from([active]);
    }
   
  })
).subscribe({
  next: buttonActive => {
    textA.value = `Button a active: ${buttonActive}`
  }
});
```

A couple issues here.  In the case that the button is toggled on, the outer observable only receives a value once the button is clicked.
This `mapTo` use seems hacky.

Any better ways to do this?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you don't want the inner observable to actually be a part of the process at all. Are you waiting on it or anything?

If not, you can just do it all as a side effect as follows:

```ts
fromEvent(buttonA, 'click').pipe(
  scan((active) => !active, false),
  tap(active => { if(active) {
    fromEvent(buttonB, 'click').pipe(
      scan(count => count+1, 0),
      tap(buttonBCount  => {
        textB.value = `button b count ${buttonBCount}`;
      })
    ).subscribe()   
  }})
).subscribe({
  next: buttonActive => {
    textA.value = `Button a active: ${buttonActive}`
  }
});
```

Nested subscriptions are considered bad voodoo, so you ca refactor like this to keep your separation of conserns more apparent:

```ts
const trackActiveFromButton$ = fromEvent(buttonA, 'click').pipe(
  scan((active) => !active, false),
  shareReplay(1)
);

trackActiveFromButton$.subscribe({
  next: buttonActive => {
    textA.value = `Button a active: ${buttonActive}`
  }
});

trackActiveFromButton$.pipe(
  switchMap(active => active ?
    fromEvent(buttonB, 'click').pipe(
      scan(count => count+1, 0),
      tap(buttonBCount  => {
        textB.value = `button b count ${buttonBCount}`;
      })
    ) :
    EMPTY
  )
).subscribe();
```

Answer (score 1):

> Any better ways to do this?

The below may be better depending on your taste.  It seems to me your sample code gets a little messy because you have a single observable that is trying to do too many things.  And the side-effects are sort of mixed in with the stream behavior logic.

It's totally fine to be use `tap()` to do side-effect type things, but sometimes it can make it harder to follow. Especially in the above code, since there is a nested observable involved.

Creating separate observables that always emit specific data can make things easier to follow.

If we declare a stream to represent the `isActive` state and subscribe to that to update `textA`, and define a `counter` stream to represent the number of clicks that occurred while `isActive = true`, using that value to update `textB`, I think it makes it easier to follow what's going on:

```
const clicksA$ = fromEvent(buttonA, 'click');
const clicksB$ = fromEvent(buttonB, 'click');

const isActive$ = clicksA$.pipe(
  scan(active => !active, false),
  startWith(false)
);

const counterB$ = combineLatest([isActive$, clicksB$]).pipe(
  scan((count, [isActive]) => isActive ? count + 1 : -1, 0)
);
   
counterB$.subscribe(
  count => textB.value = count === -1 ? '' :`button b count ${count}`
);

isActive$.subscribe(
    isActive => textA.value = `Button a active: ${isActive}`
);
```

To me, having the streams defined separately makes it easier to see the relationship between them, meaning, it's easier to tell when they will emit:

- `isActive` derives from `clicksA`
- `counterB` derives from `clicksB` & `isActive`

Here's a working [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-66050842?file=index.ts)

Also:

> the outer observable only receives a value once the button is clicked

This can be solved using [`startWith()`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/startwith) to emit a default value.